# Python typing, pickle and serialisation

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle, typing

I've started learning the typing system in python and came across an issue in defining function arguments that are picklable. Not everything in python can be pickled, can I define a type annotation that says "only accept objects that can are picklable"?

At first it sounds like something that should be possible, similar to Java's `Serializable` but then there is no `Picklable` interface in python and thinking about the issue a little more it occurs to me that pickling is an inherently runtime task. [What can be pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) lists a number of things that can be pickled, and it's not difficult to imagine a container of lambda functions which would not be picklable, but I can't think of a way of determining that before hand (without touching the container definition).

The only way I've come up with is to define something like a `typing.Union[Callable, Iterable, ...]` of all the things listed in [What can be pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) but that does not seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

This issue on github partially answers the question, although the issue is specifically related to `json` not `pickle` but the first answer from Guido should still apply to `pickle`

> I tried to do that but a recursive type alias doesn't work in mypy right now, and I'm not sure how to make it work. In the mean time I use JsonDict = Dict[str, Any] (which is not very useful but at least clarifies that the keys are strings), and Any for places where a more general JSON type is expected.

https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182